# How to add validations to a radio button in angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms

This is my form in angular.

hotel.component.html:

```
<div class="container-sm">

  <div class="bg-light jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>Hotel</h2>

  </div>
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSubmit()" class="mb-3">

    <div class="col">
      <label class="form-label fw-bold">Ammenities:</label>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="form-check me-4">

          <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" value="Pool" formControlName="option"> Pool </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" value="Laundry" formControlName="option"> Laundry </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div *ngIf="form.controls['option'].touched && form.controls['option'].invalid">
      <div *ngIf="form.controls['option'].hasError('required')" class="error">Please select an option</div>
    </div>
    </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

hotel.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, Location } from '@angular/common';

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder,FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

export class HotelComponent {
//
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {


    this.form = this.fb.group({
      option: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
        console.log(option);

          
        }
     }
}
```

Just a simple form with a radio and a submit button. If user tries to submit the form without selecting any options, the error message should be shown. Right now ,no error message appears when I click on submit without selecting ana option.

Can someone tell me how to make the validation work?

Comment: For checkboxes you need to use Validators.requiredTrue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a condition that if your control is touched and invalid then only show the error. Talking about this condition which needs to be fixed:

```
<div *ngIf="form.controls['option'].touched && form.controls['option'].invalid">
      <div *ngIf="form.controls['option'].hasError('required')" class="error">Please select an option</div>
</div>
```

To fix this issue either you can mark your control touched or remove touched condition from your HTML code. `form.controls['option'].touched`

Component side to mark control tocuhed:

```
 this.form = this.fb.group({
      option: ['', Validators.required],
    });
 this.form.controls['option'].markAsTouched();
```

Moreover if you want to disable button if none of the options are selected then you can use this contion on button:

`[disabled]="form.invalid"`

Comment: Marking the radio as touched on init will display the error before the user actually touches it. What you can actually do, is mark all the form as touched in the `onSubmit`, so errors will only show after touching the radio or submitting

Comment: @Devang Paul So tried what u said "

To fix this issue either you can mark your control touched or remove touched condition from your HTML code. form.controls['option'].touched' .                          But either way it displays error before the user actually touches it.

Comment: You can move `this.form.controls['option'].markAsTouched();` into resubmit button() if you want to show case after click on submit button.

Comment: @DevangPatel it worked, thanks for the tip. It wasn't the only one with which i needed help with but a lott. By doing so , it all worked .

Comment: @Random it worked, thanks for the tip. It wasn't the only one with which i needed help with but a lott. By doing so , it all worked

Answer (score 1):

`touched` property doesn't work as expected for radio buttons in Angular. Instead, you can use the `form.get('option').value` to check if the radio button value is null or empty to determine if it has been touched or not. Declare a boolean property to track the form submission status.

Here is the working snippet [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/full-angular-reactive-forms-demo-hmavly?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Html**

```
<div class="container-sm">
  <div class="bg-light jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>Hotel</h2>
  </div>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSubmit()" class="mb-3">
    <div class="col">
      <label class="form-label fw-bold">Ammenities:</label>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="form-check me-4">
          <label class="form-check-label"
            ><input
              class="form-check-input"
              type="radio"
              name="option"
              value="Pool"
              formControlName="option"
            />
            Pool
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label"
            ><input
              class="form-check-input"
              type="radio"
              name="option"
              value="Laundry"
              formControlName="option"
            />
            Laundry
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div *ngIf="form.get('option')?.invalid && (form.get('option')?.value === null || form.get('option')?.value === '') && submitted" class="error">
    Please select an option.
  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<br />
<br />
```

**ts**

```
 form: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      option: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const option = this.form.value.option;
      console.log(option);
    }
  }
```

Comment: hey, it works in stackblitz, but in VS Code, I get errors in these lines "          form.get('option').**invalid** &&
          (form.get('option').**value** === null ||
            form.get('option').**value** === '') &&
          submitted"                                                                                                                             as "Object is possibly 'null' " for "invalid" and "value".

Comment: @zack replace with this using null check <div *ngIf="form.get('option')?.invalid && (form.get('option')?.value === null || form.get('option')?.value === '') && submitted" class="error">
    Please select an option.
  </div>

Comment: Appreciate ur effort . The answer which I marked correct worked after making some changes. Tq

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about FormBuilder, Formgroup, ... but using Two-way binding is easier to understand
You can replace the Input radio elements in your HTML page with these

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="option" name="option" value="Pool">
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="option" name="option" value="Laundry">
<div *ngIf="error">{{error}}</div><!-- Displays error -->
```

Typescript Page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, Location } from '@angular/common';

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder,FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';


export class HotelComponent {
//
  option?: string;
  form: FormGroup;
  error?: string;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {


    this.form = this.fb.group({
      option: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if(!this.option) {
       //if option value is undefined (not selected)
       this.error = "Choose an option";
       console.log(error);
       return;
    }
    if (this.form.valid) {
        console.log(option);

          
    }
  }
}
```